# What's wrong with this CALayer setup code

Tags: ios, calayer

The [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/ViewPG_iPhoneOS.pdf) on pg. 57 has this piece of code:

```
// Create the layer.
CALayer* myLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
// Set the contents of the layer to a fixed image. And set
// the size of the layer to match the image size.
UIImage layerContents = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] retain];
CGSize imageSize = layerContents.size;
myLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
myLayer = layerContents.CGImage;
```

Why would you want to do this in the last line: `myLayer = layerContents.CGImage;`. For one thing, the objects don't match up so it's a type problem. But it's replacing the object created in the first statement!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that document is wrong. It should probably be:

```
myLayer.contents = (id)layerContents.CGImage;
```

This is one way to set the contents of a layer. See the [docs for `contents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW24)